# Which of these Tags are better

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design

I'm designing a flow that includes adding a special tag to a flight listing component for mobile. This special tag doesn't appear on all flights of the listing and there will be a mix of flights with and without the tag.

For both options, there is more info that needs to be accessible. In option A. this info can be accessed via the (i) in the tab. In option B the same info can be accessed under the "more info" section. Both options have a "more info" section that includes other info not related to the tag. (Also I'm a bit concerned that the (i) is too hard to be pressed and too close to other touch areas)

[image]

Of these, which would be your choice and why? would there be other better options that I haven't considered? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is to make the "more info >" button do the job for *both* cases.

You can do this by moving the "Special Flight" tag to be next to the "more info" link. It still stands out, and it becomes clear that the user can click "more info" to learn more about the special flight details.

Also, if you haven't done so already. I suggest making the whole bottom bar clickable rather than just the "more info" link text.

Here is an example to help demonstrate my suggestion, please excuse the rushed editing:

[image]

[image]